# Dynamic UTMs to Track Customer Buying Behavior

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, google-analytics

I'm currently facing a challenge with our email marketing campaign at SFMC. We want to send a promotional email to customers who have bought a specific item. The problem is that we don't yet have transactional data in Marketing Cloud.

Here's what I'm considering: I want to add dynamic UTMs to each user to identify them in Marketing Cloud. My plan is to use Google Analytics data, which provides information on the items purchased by users. By creating unique dynamic UTMs, I believe we can effectively track customers who have purchased the specific item.

I'm looking for guidance on how to generate these dynamic UTMs for each user.

Has anyone implemented a similar solution and knows if it's possible? If so, could you share your ideas or provide an example of how to create dynamic UTMs for each user in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

I'd appreciate any tips and advice on the subject.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The standard GA connector in SFMC will add subscriber ID to the query string. BUT you will not be able to pick up these individual IDs from GA - only aggregated segments are available, even if you have GA360

Comment: Even if I add a unique identifier for each person in the UTM (for example, as a custom parameter in the URL), can I not track these identifiers in Google Analytics?